# Access Play variables from vars_promt programatically

Tags: ansible

I have a playbook including some vars_promt

```
vars_prompt:
  - name: domain_username
    prompt: "Domain username? (firstname.lastname)"
    private: no
  - name: domain_password
    prompt: "Domain password?"
    private: yes
  - name: pref_editor
    prompt: "[A]tom or [V]isual Studio Code?"
    private: no
```

I now would like to access these variables programatically, something like

```
hostvars[inventory_hostname][variable]
```

where `variable` would be e.g. `domain_username`

However, the variables from `vars_prompt` are not inclueded in `hostvars`, and looking through the documentation I cannot find out which variable holds that scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vars_prompt` variables are in `Play` scope. They are equal for all hosts in the current play and can be referenced by name:

```
- debug: var=domain_username
```

`hostvars` holds host facts. If you need to access your prompt vars in later plays, you can set fact like:

```
- set_fact:
    domain_username_fact: "{{ domain_username }}"
```

So it becomes a fact for host and available as `hostvars['some host'].domain_username_fact`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this is more a workaround than what I needed

Answer (score 0):

While I still haven't found any documentation, I did find this [snipped](https://coderwall.com/p/13lh6w/dump-all-variables)

The relevant part is this:

```
Module Variables ("vars"):
--------------------------------
{{ vars | to_nice_json }}
```

So instead of accessing the variable as `hostvars[inventory_hostname][variable]`, I can access it as `vars[variable]`

Comment: Are you sure this is what you need? `vars[variable]` is a hack, and vars accessed this way are not templated. And what is the reason to access `vars[variable]` instead of just `variable`?

Comment: the reason is that variable contains the name of the variable not the contents, and in the role i wrote the name is dynamic, because i want to persist variables on the host (similar to facts.d)

Comment: Could you elaborate how `vars` is a hack? I just can't find any documentation on it.

Comment: See [this](https://gist.github.com/berlic/26a427ea613a8b2edbbb114ece93d2b1) simple demo for example.

Comment: I see, that's really not an expected behavior, thanks for pointing it out!